# Dynamically generate innerHTML elements from a response array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, dom

I'm a novice using JavaScript syntax and am having trouble adapting any solutions I find to match this.

**This is a part of my code:**
var arr1 = response;
console.log(arr1);

****This is the response/console logged arr1:**

```json
{
  "channels": {
    "1620184778889x527731420801269760": [
      {
        "channel": "1620184778889x527731420801269760",
        "timetoken": "16204064644032062",
        "message": {
          "content": "44444444444",
          "sender": "Jeremy"
        },
        "messageType": null,
        "uuid": "1617237881603x986210451354598100"
      }
    ],
    "1618599897203x154294096401530880": [
      {
        "channel": "1618599897203x154294096401530880",
        "timetoken": "16203351496721278",
        "message": {
          "content": "fffffffdd",
          "sender": "Jeremy"
        },
        "messageType": null,
        "uuid": "1617237881603x986210451354598100"
      }
    ],
    "1618613571551x955443898854408200": [
      {
        "channel": "1618613571551x955443898854408200",
        "timetoken": "16204261556065826",
        "message": {
          "content": "78777",
          "sender": "Jeremy"
        },
        "messageType": null,
        "uuid": "1617237881603x986210451354598100"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Trying to:**

I need to get the following data:
1.channel
2.timetoken
3.message > content
4.message > sender

And then I need to dynamically generate an innerHTML property for each channel in the array (the amount of channels will frequently vary).

*Something like this for each channel returned (incorrect syntax, just an example):*
document.getElementById(*channel*).innerHTML  = *sender* + ' ' + *content* + ' ' + *timetoken*;

I am having difficulty adapting other similar solutions to retrieve the nested array items and use loops. I think I need a loop to go through the channels to retrieve the data and also a loop to generate the innerHTML items, but I have been trying for days and can't get it, I am hoping someone well versed can assist.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Can you share how you want to show it in html, or can share how the `channel` it element looks like in html?

Comment: For every channel (in the array "Channels") there will be a <p id="channel"></p> in the html. (id="channel" being the string of numbers for each, not the word "channel"). That's already done dynamically.

I'm trying to write the array data from each channel into that p element. 

The final result in the html (for each) would look like
<p id="channel-number">Sender Content Timetoken</p>

So I am trying to write the "Sender Content Timetoken" data from each channel to its corresponding ID (Which is the channel string of numbers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>

<script>

    let dataObject = {
        "channels": {

            "1620184778889x527731420801269760": [

                {

                    "channel": "1620184778889x527731420801269760",

                    "timetoken": "16204064644032062",

                    "message": {

                        "content": "44444444444",

                        "sender": "Jeremy"

                    },

                    "messageType": null,

                    "uuid": "1617237881603x986210451354598100"

                }

            ],

            "1618599897203x154294096401530880": [

                {

                    "channel": "1618599897203x154294096401530880",

                    "timetoken": "16203351496721278",

                    "message": {

                        "content": "fffffffdd",

                        "sender": "Jeremy"

                    },

                    "messageType": null,

                    "uuid": "1617237881603x986210451354598100"

                }

            ],

            "1618613571551x955443898854408200": [

                {

                    "channel": "1618613571551x955443898854408200",

                    "timetoken": "16204261556065826",

                    "message": {

                        "content": "78777",

                        "sender": "Jeremy"

                    },

                    "messageType": null,

                    "uuid": "1617237881603x986210451354598100"

                }

            ]

        }
    }
    for (let channelName in dataObject.channels) {
        for (let item of dataObject.channels[channelName]) {
            const channel = item.channel;
            const timetoken = item.timetoken;
            const content = item.message.content;
            const sender = item.message.sender;
            const messageType = item.messageType;
            const uuid = item.uuid;
            // do whatever you want with these data
            console.log(channel, timetoken, content, sender, messageType, uuid);
        }
    }


</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You helped me so much!! This is perfect.